# I can't get image from PFFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pffile

Parse.com just updated their SDKs to support local storage. But after installing new SDKs I have occurred some problems with PFFile. I have used the same method for a long time, but now that I'm using the new SDK I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFFile *iconPhoto;
```

.m file

```
cell.iconPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]; // placeholder image
cell.iconPhoto.file = (PFFile *)object[@"icon"]; // remote image
[cell.iconPhoto loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
    cell.iconPhoto.image = image;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

   }];
```

When I run, I get [these errors (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIEST.png)

Is someone else having the same problems?

**UPDATE:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    });

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MainTVCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *object = [self.currentCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.mainLabel.text = object[@"name"];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if (![object[@"icon"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

        cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]; // placeholder image
        cell.iconPhoto = (PFFile *)object[@"icon"]; // remote image
        [cell.iconPhoto getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && imageData) {
                cell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            }

        }];


    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Oh, you just changed your screen cap... And your code in the screen cap isn't the same as the code here...

Comment: You're combining two separate concepts... If you're using a PFImageView using `getDataInBackground` is unnecessary.

Comment: You just deleted your comment... Which is the PFImageView?

Comment: @LyndseyScott sorry, I mixed up the screenshots.. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Which is the PFImageView?

Comment: @LyndseyScott in the .h file, I used 'PFImageView' instead of 'PFFile' before, but they removed 'PFImageView' when they updated the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

```
 PFFile *file = (PFFile *)object[@"icon"];
[file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]; // placeholder image
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}];
```

This will load the images.
Weird thing it won't run in the simulator.. But works perfectly on iPhone.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the placeholder image inside the block.