# Load user image

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I use this code to load users usernames when a user search for another user

```
var user: PFUser? {

        didSet {
            userNameLabel.text = user?.username
        }

    }
```

How can I do the same thing but for profile pictures?

Comment: have tried to search on the other questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490602/loading-image-in-swift-from-parse

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

**case 1**

If you need to download the image and display then -

1. Create a property that holds url for the image.
2. Asynchronously download image and display

So code would look this this

```
var pictureURL: NSURL? 
var user: PFUser? {

        didSet {
            userNameLabel.text = user?.username
            pictureURL = user?.pictureURL
            displayPicture()
        }

    }

    private func displayPicture() {
    // Async download pic and display
    }
```

**case 2**
If you have the image locally then just display -

```
var user: PFUser? {

        didSet {
            userNameLabel.text = user?.username
            userImage.image = UIImage(named: "Picturename")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Anupam my user images are stored with Parse

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** save your image file with `UIImage` format on **Parse.com**. You can store the file with `PFFile` and you have to **convert** your image to `PFFile` for **saving and getting** the image.

You can save your Image with this function;

```
 private func saveLogo() {
    let yourLogoImageFile = UIImage(named: "YourLogoFileName")
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourLogoImageFile!, 0.1) {
        // You got the PFFile you can use this for save.
        let imagePFFile = PFFile(name: "logo.png", data: imageData)
        logo = imagePFFile // Send this PFFile to your variable or just save.
        // Saving...
        imagePFFile?.saveInBackground()
    }
}
```

After that you can get your logo `PFFile` from Parse and you have to convert it to `UIImage` with this function;

```
    private func getLogo() {
    if let image = yourLogoVariable {
        image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock() {
            (let imageData, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let logoImageData = imageData {
                    if let logoImage = UIImage(data: logoImageData) {
                        // logoImage is the UIImage you can use this for your UIImageView.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @emresancaktar, Thanks for your answer. But i'm not trying to get just one image. I'm trying to get the profile_picture of all the user. For example: when a person search for another user I want them to see the user profile picture too, not only the username. This code works perfectly to display all usernames : var user: PFUser? {

        didSet {
            userNameLabel.text = user?.username
        }

    }

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting the quality of the JPEG to `0.1`... That will begin to have a lot of artifacts - `0.6` or `0.7` would be better